# Html::img tag not working in yii2

Tags: html, image, yii2

I am new to yii2 and I am trying to add images to my website with the help of Html::img tag but I keep getting broken links on the website. I am using wamp.  This is my code:

```
<?= Html::img('@web/images/logo.png', ['alt' => 'My logo']) ?>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should conver to an url your alias

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

...

<?= Html::img(    Url::to('@web/images/logo.png'), ['alt' => 'My logo']) ?>
```

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, I tried your suggestion but still the same broken image.

Comment: Could you update your question and adding the result for var_dump(Url::to('@web/images/logo.png')) and can you confirm that  your img is inside   web/images/?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <?php $domain = yii\helpers\Url::base(true);
      echo Html::img($domain.'/images/logo.png', ['alt' => 'My logo']) 
  ?>
```

Comment: Hi Mohan, your suggestion isn't working either. Could there be something wrong with my code?

Comment: I have checked the page source and the url given is <img src="http://localhost/tililsmsplatform/images/logo.png" alt="My logo"> which I think is alright, so maybe there is a problem with my code or what?

Comment: Image source should be like  : `<img src="http://localhost/tililsmsplatform/images/logo.png"; alt="My logo">`

Comment: Actually I am the one who got it wrong, this is it <img src="http://localhost/tililsmsplatform/images/logo.png" alt="My logo">

Comment: sorry, the http:// part is not copied when I copy paste, but it is there in the image source.

Comment: You can check by adding manually `http://` in your image source, is that a problem of http or not?